# Add a ribbon instead of menubar and toolbar in a dialog based project - VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog, ribbon

I must edit an existing MFC dialog-based project. I must replace the menubar and toolbar with a ribbon. The project is made in VS2010. It can't be created again from scratch(would be a pain in the @$$, because it's enormous!). The only information I could find was that it isn't impossible. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

In general I would convert the project into a standard SDI application with a CFormView.

CDialog isn't prepared for all those things needed to hold a ribbon.

PS: I would only choose a CDialog bases exe if I never use things like toolbars and all this things that are usually easily to implement in a SDI/MDI application.

Comment: Can I just the needed frame class with the needed variables and methods and use it instead of the dialog? I mean' without changing the project?

Comment: It is easier to create a new SDI project with a ribbon and a CFormView and just copy the Dialog code into the CFormView class...

Comment: The whole project is +1GB :/

Comment: Anyhow... The of your dialog application can be shifted into a doc/view architecture. I see no chance to get the ribbon stuff into a dialog. 1GB source?... wow and tis a s a dialog :) I am sure that you can get a bunch of you surcecode into a doc/view app without changing a line of code.

Comment: Currently I'm trying to repalce the dialog with a frame. Would that help?

Comment: Yes! This would help. But that's the same like using a CFrameWnd with a CFormView... ;)

Comment: For now I have two problems: 1. IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE is underscored and when I point it, it sais "inherited member is not allowed". The output says " 'CreateObject' : member function not declared in 'CMainFrame' ". Still works fine in a standalone project o.O 2. I think I have a multiple include issue because I get an error saying that one of the functions is redefined. But when I track it, I don't see any redefinition anywhere.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set DECLARE_DYNCREATE in the class.

Comment: Yup... My favourite type of mistakes :D One down, one to go